# What are 'if ,define, lambda' in scheme?

Tags: c++, lambda, scheme, lisp

We have a course whose project is to implement a micro-scheme interpreter in C++. In my implementation, I treat 'if', 'define', 'lambda' as procedures, so it is valid in my implementation to eval 'if', 'define' or 'lambda', and it is also fine to write expressions like '(apply define (quote (a 1)))', which will bind 'a' to 1.

But I find in racket and in mit-scheme, 'if', 'define', 'lambda' are not evaluable. For example,

[image]

It seems that they are not procedures, but I cannot figure out what they are and how they are implemented.
Can someone explain these to me?

Comment: These are core 'forms' or macros. You implement them in the compiler.

Comment: In your implementation, what happens if you do `(if #f (display true) (display false))`?

Comment: My implementation doesn't have the keyword 'display', so the expression will be an error. But if it changes to (if #f (print 'true) (print 'false)),  (#f (print 'true) (print 'false)) will be passed to procedure if, it will first eval #f and find the condition is false, and then it will eval (print 'false), so it will print out "false"

Comment: I must clarify that what I have implemented is just an interpreter, not a compiler

Comment: Maybe your tutor in the course can help you. I think it is best to ask her/him. Stackoverflow is best when you've done some research and have a real programming problem. It is not that effective as a course tutor. Maybe there are other in the course, who can help you find some literature, where the basic semantics of Scheme is described.

Comment: @KaoLian The point that sepp2k was trying to make is that the sort of conditional evaluation you describe (check the condition, then do *either* the then or the else part) is not how *function* application is typically handled in Scheme (and most other languages in the Lisp family).  E.g., if you evaluate `(foo (print 'true) (print 'false))`, then both of the arguments are evaluated.  If your interpreter handles `if` differently, then you're not really treating it as a function/procedure.  That's *good*, because you don't want to evaluate all the arguments to `if`, `define`, `lambda`, etc.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Besides from being primitives they could be functions if the language is lazy. Scheme usually is an eager language.

Comment: @Sylwester Yes, that's what I was alluding to when I said "typically handled in Scheme (and most other languages in the Lisp family)."

Comment: Thanks for everyone's comment, now I see where I was wrong when implementing the interpreter

Comment: This may help clarify: https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=lisp+special+forms

Answer (score 1):

In the terminology of Lisp, expressions to be evaluated are *forms*. Compound forms (those which use list syntax) are divided into special forms (headed by *special operators* like *let*), macro forms, and function call forms.

The Scheme report desn't use this terminology. It calls functions "procedures". Scheme's special forms are called "syntax".  Macros are "derived expression types", individually introduced as "library syntax". (The motivation for this may be some conscious decision to blend into the CS academic mainstream by scrubbing some unfamiliar Lisp terminology. Algol has procedures and a BNF-defined syntax, Scheme has procedures and a BNF-defined syntax. That ticks off some sort of familiarity checkbox.)

Special forms (or "syntax") are recognized by interpreters and compilers as a set of special cases. The interpreter or compiler may handle these forms via function-like bindings in some internal table keyed on symbols, but it's not the program-visible binding namespace.

Setting up these associations in the regular namespace isn't necessarily wrong, but it could be problematic. If you want both a compiler and interpreter, but *let* has only one top-level binding, that will be an issue: who gets to install their procedure into that binding: the interpreter or compiler? (One way to resolve that is simple: make the binding values `cons` pairs: the `car` can be the interpreter function, the `cdr` the compiler function. But then these bindings are not procedures any more that you can *apply*.)

Exposing these bindings to the application is problematic anyway, because the semantics is so different between interpretation and compilation. If your interpretation is interpreted, then calling the `define` binding as a function is possible; it has the effect of performing the definition. But in a compiled interpretation, code depending on this won't work; `define` will be a function that doesn't actually define anything, but rather compiles: it calculates and returns a compiled fragment written in some intermediate representation.

About your implementation, the fact that `(apply define (quote (a 1)))` works in your implementation raises a bit of a red flag. Either you've made the environment parameter of the function optional, or it doesn't take one. Functions implementing special operators (or "syntax") need an environment parameter, not just the piece of syntax. (At least if we are developing a lexically scoped Scheme or Lisp!)

The fact that `(apply define (quote (a 1)))` works also suggests that your `define` function is taking `quote` and `(a 1)` as arguments.  While that is workable, the usual approach for these kinds of syntax procedures is to take *the whole form* as one argument (and a lexical environment as another argument). If such a function can be called, the invocation looks something like  like `(apply define (list '(define a 1) (null-environment 5)))`.   The procedure itself will do any necessary destructuring on the syntax, and checking for validity: are there too many or too few parameters and so on.